# PHP & Twig : Trouble accessing variables in template

Tags: php, twig, slim, phpactiverecord

In my controller I am setting the following variables and passing them to the Twig template:

```
$data = $model::all(); // returns object [phpactiverecord]
$fields = getFields(); // returns associative array
```

In my template, I am attempting the access them like this:

```
{% block rows %}
  {% for row in data %}
            <tr>
    {% for field in fields %}
              <td>{{ row[field.name] }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
            </tr>
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

In this scenario, $fields is defined as:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => id
            [display] => Id
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => name
            [display] => Name
        )

)
```

and $data is an array of phpactiverecord objects.

---

As written above, nothing is output for row[field.name].

Here are the results I see if I change row[field.name]:

```
row.name        -> outputs Value I would expect from row[field.name]
field.name      -> outputs "name"
row['name']     -> outputs nothing
row[field.name] -> outputs nothing
```

---

According to the [Twig site](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html): You can use a dot (.) to access attributes of a variable (methods or properties of a PHP object, or items of a PHP array), or the so-called “subscript” syntax ([]):

Any ideas on getting this to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using version 1.2 or later, try the [`attribute`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/attribute.html) function

```
{{ attribute(row, field.name) }}
```

It's even mentioned on the [page you linked to](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#variables)...

> If you want to get a dynamic attribute on a variable, use the attribute function instead.